# Sql sum of new columns

Tags: sql-server, sum

I have a part of a query below where I have created new columns based on conditions:

```
select 
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Errors,
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent between 0 and 3 then 1 else 0 end) as _0_3_days,
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as _4_days,
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as _5_days,
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent between 6 and 8 then 1 else 0 end) as _6_8_days,
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent >= 9 then 1 else 0 end) as more_than_9_days,

   avg(case when Overall_Time_Spent < 0 then 100.0 else 0 end) as Errors_percent,
   avg(case when Overall_Time_Spent between 0 and 3 then 100.0 else 0 end) as _0_3_percent,
   avg(case when Overall_Time_Spent = 4 then 100.0 else 0 end) as _4_percent,
   avg(case when Overall_Time_Spent = 5 then 100.0 else 0 end) as _5_percent,
   avg(case when Overall_Time_Spent between 6 and 8 then 100.0 else 0 end) as _6_8_percent,
   avg(case when Overall_Time_Spent >= 9 then 100.0 else 0 end) as more_than_9_days_percent,
```

How can I add a query within this one where I can add TWO MORE columns which give me sum of all the sums and sum of all of avg

Thanks in advance

Comment: Either do it on an outer scope, or just add another with the full range of your values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CASE` expressions you have covers `<0`, between `0` and `8` and `>=9`, which is **every possibility**, provided that your data is an `int`. Thus, all you need to add is

```
COUNT(Overall_Time_Spent) AS DaysTotal
```

If it isn't an `int`, then your `CASE` expressions will miss values between `3` and `4`, `4` and `5`, `5` and `6` and `8` and `9`, however, the `COUNT` would include them.

Comment: This is the easiest solution but it's worth mentioning that it works if the OP's column is int (values like 3.5 are not handled in his sums).

Comment: Very true @Ezlo. One would *hope* that that isn't the case, based on the logic. I'll, however, add the caveat to the answer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add an important bit, I have two sets of columns, please see updated. I need totals for both groups of columns

Answer (score 1):

Try to use subquery:

```
SELECT a.*, (Errors + _0_3_days...) as Total FROM (
select 
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Errors,
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent between 0 and 3 then 1 else 0 end) as _0_3_days,
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as _4_days,
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as _5_days,
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent between 6 and 8 then 1 else 0 end) as _6_8_days,
   sum(case when Overall_Time_Spent >= 9 then 1 else 0 end) as more_than_9_days
) as a
```